# Rearrange Points on Grid based on Heatmap Intensity Keeping Grid Pattern

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, heatmap

I'm working on a project where I need to rearrange points on a grid based on the intensity values in a heatmap image. My goal is to have higher point density in areas with high heatmap intensity and lower density in areas with low intensity, while maintaining the overall grid pattern as much as possible.

**Problem:**

I've provided some sample code that draws a fixed grid on top of the heatmap image. However, I need help achieving the following:

**1. Dynamic Point Spacing:**
How can I modify the code to adjust the spacing between points based on the heatmap intensity at each grid cell?

**2. Smooth Adjustment:** I want the point density transition between cells to be smooth and avoid abrupt changes.

**3. Grid Structure Preservation:** While adjusting point density, I want to maintain the
overall grid pattern to the best possible extent.

**4. Fixed Number of Points:** The total number of points on the grid must remain constant
throughout the process.

My current code draws a fixed grid using drawGrid function.
I'm open to different approaches, including resampling the points based on the heatmap while maintaining the grid structure.
Can you please help me modify my code or suggest an approach to achieve the desired point rearrangement based on the heatmap intensity, while considering the aforementioned constraints?

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void drawGrid(Mat& image, int gridX, int gridY, vector<Point>& gridPoints) {
    int cellWidth = image.cols / gridX;
    int cellHeight = image.rows / gridY;

    for (int i = 0; i < gridX; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < gridY; ++j) {
            int x = i * cellWidth;
            int y = j * cellHeight;
            circle(image, Point(x, y), 1, Scalar(255, 0, 0), 2, LINE_AA);
            gridPoints.push_back(Point(x, y));
        }
    }

    cout << "Fixed: Total No of Samples: " << gridPoints.size()
        << ", from " << gridX << " x " << gridY << " Grid" << endl;
}

void displayAndSaveImage(const string& windowName, const Mat& image, const string& fileName) {
    imshow(windowName, image);
    imwrite(fileName, image);
}


int main() {
    const string inputImagePath = "Heat Map.png";
    const string outputImagePath = "1_Fixed Grid Image.png";
    const int gridX = 35, gridY = 35;

    // Load the image in grayscale and convert to BGR
    Mat HeatMap = imread(inputImagePath, IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    if (HeatMap.empty()) {
        cerr << "Error loading the image" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    cvtColor(HeatMap, HeatMap, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);

    // Draw grid on the image
    vector<Point> gridPoints;
    drawGrid(HeatMap, gridX, gridY, gridPoints);

    // Display and save the image with the grid
    displayAndSaveImage("1_Fixed Grid Image", HeatMap, outputImagePath);

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

**Input Image:** [image]

**Fixed Grid Output:** [image]

**So far what I've tried:**

Variable Grid version 1:
[image]

Variable Grid version 2:
[image]

Comment: why does it have to be a grid? do you consider your first picture to have achieved your goal? -- what are the rules for decimating the grid? -- take a look at dithering algorithms for inspiration